# php mysql command for daily report

Tags: mysql, report

I have a mysql table with some entries. sample data

```
nid   |   news_date
1     | 16 July 2015, 2:31 pm
2     | 16 July 2015, 2:31 pm
3     | 17 July 2015, 12:31 pm
4     | 18 July 2015, 4:28 pm
5     | 20 July 2015, 12:31 pm
```

I want daily report, and i tried with this sql command

```
SELECT count(nid), DATE(news_date) 
FROM tbl_news 
GROUP BY DATE(tbl_news.news_date);
```

But i am getting output as

```
count(nid) | DATE(news_date)
   5       | NULL
```

But i want daily record count report, Anybody help.

Comment: What is the data type of `news_date` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this query:-

```
SELECT count(nid), news_date 
FROM tbl_news 
GROUP BY (STR_TO_DATE(tbl_news.news_date, '%d %M %Y')) ;
```

I have removed the date keyword.

Comment: Did u get ur expected O/P using above answer?

Comment: Ok. For `16 July 2015, 2:31 pm` it shows how many rows? For 16 July it shows one row or two rows. If it is two rows for same record then there is some spacing in your date value. Can u plz check.

Comment: Count 2 or rows 2? If you get count as 2 for 16 july then u get ur expected o/p.

Comment: But did u get the expected result using above query or not.

Comment: count is 2, since the date and time are equal. Assume if the time is different then it shows count as 1. I dont want to check the time. Confused!

Comment: Did u get the ans or I can help u out.

Comment: i haven't got the answer. i want daily report. If there is 3 data with same date but with different time, it shows count as 1

Comment: You are always welcome dude... If you need any help in DB plz let me know.

Comment: Is there any way to get report for 17 July to 20 July. I tried with BETWEEN query, but fails.

Comment: Can u paste me the query that u have tried. So that I can help u out.

Comment: Try this query:- `SELECT count(nid), news_date 
FROM tbl_news WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(tbl_news.news_date, '%d %M %Y')) between '2015-07-17' AND '2015-07-20' GROUP BY (STR_TO_DATE(tbl_news.news_date, '%d %M %Y'))`